# Exclude urls from spring-starter-security

Tags: java, spring, security

I have a problem using springboot-starter-security. I want to secure only urls that does not begin with "/api", all urls such as "/api" or "/api/" or "/api/**" must no be secured.

In WebSecurityConfigClass I have:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api*");

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

In the application I have two different controllers, webcontroller and restcontroller. For the moment web isn't yet implemented but it must address urls that i want to be secured, the rest controller manage urls that i want not to need an authentication. 
I have a test class for the rest controller, and all tests fails because they are expecting a 200 as status, but they receive 401. For example:

```
@Test
public void testStatus200() throws Exception{
    mvc.perform(get("/api")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

this test fails due to status is 401 and not 200. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the test class did not use the websecurityconfig class.
I fixed by adding an explicit import of the WebSecurityConfig as class annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers=ARestController.class)
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class) // <---
public class ARestControllerTest { ... }
```